# Remove the duplicates from the dictionary in list based on playerid and Series key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have data like this

```
 Datas = 

[{'playerid': 'ABCD2612', 'Series': 'U11', 'Points': [810.0, 360.0, 360.0, 251.25]}
{'playerid': 'CDEF2077', 'Series': 'U13', 'Points': [810.0, 540.0, 270.0, 270.0]}
{'playerid': 'HIJK0140', 'Series': 'U15', 'Points': [810.0, 675.0, 540.0, 540.0]}
{'playerid': 'LMNO0315', 'Series': 'U17', 'Points': [945.0, 810.0, 675.0, 540.0]}
{'playerid': 'ABCD2612', 'Series': 'U11', 'Points': [810.0, 360.0, 360.0, 251.25]}
{'playerid': 'CDEF2077', 'Series': 'U13', 'Points': [810.0, 540.0, 270.0, 270.0]}
{'playerid': 'HIJK0140', 'Series': 'U15', 'Points': [810.0, 675.0, 540.0, 540.0]}
{'playerid': 'LMNO0315', 'Series': 'U17', 'Points': [945.0, 810.0, 675.0, 540.0]}]
```

I need to remove the duplicates from Datas based on playerid and Series

output look like this

```
output = 

[{'playerid': 'ABCD2612', 'Series': 'U11', 'Points': [810.0, 360.0, 360.0, 251.25]}
{'playerid': 'CDEF2077', 'Series': 'U13', 'Points': [810.0, 540.0, 270.0, 270.0]}
{'playerid': 'HIJK0140', 'Series': 'U15', 'Points': [810.0, 675.0, 540.0, 540.0]}
{'playerid': 'LMNO0315', 'Series': 'U17', 'Points': [945.0, 810.0, 675.0, 540.0]}]
```

thanks for your contributions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `set` and a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'playerid': 'ABCD2612', 'Series': 'U11', 'Points': [810.0, 360.0, 360.0, 251.25]},
{'playerid': 'CDEF2077', 'Series': 'U13', 'Points': [810.0, 540.0, 270.0, 270.0]},
{'playerid': 'HIJK0140', 'Series': 'U15', 'Points': [810.0, 675.0, 540.0, 540.0]},
{'playerid': 'LMNO0315', 'Series': 'U17', 'Points': [945.0, 810.0, 675.0, 540.0]},
{'playerid': 'ABCD2612', 'Series': 'U11', 'Points': [810.0, 360.0, 360.0, 251.25]},
{'playerid': 'CDEF2077', 'Series': 'U13', 'Points': [810.0, 540.0, 270.0, 270.0]},
{'playerid': 'HIJK0140', 'Series': 'U15', 'Points': [810.0, 675.0, 540.0, 540.0]},
{'playerid': 'LMNO0315', 'Series': 'U17', 'Points': [945.0, 810.0, 675.0, 540.0]}]

seen = set()
res = []
for i in data:
    key = (i['playerid'],i['Series'])
    if key not in seen:   #Check if playerid & Series in set
        res.append(i) 
        seen.add(key)

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Points': [810.0, 360.0, 360.0, 251.25],
  'Series': 'U11',
  'playerid': 'ABCD2612'},
 {'Points': [810.0, 540.0, 270.0, 270.0],
  'Series': 'U13',
  'playerid': 'CDEF2077'},
 {'Points': [810.0, 675.0, 540.0, 540.0],
  'Series': 'U15',
  'playerid': 'HIJK0140'},
 {'Points': [945.0, 810.0, 675.0, 540.0],
  'Series': 'U17',
  'playerid': 'LMNO0315'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind data order, you can use a simple dictionary to remove duplicated items:

```
out = {(x['playerid'], x['Series']):x for x in Datas}.values()
```

If you want to keep the original data order, you have to keep track of item positions:

```
out = [x[1] for x in sorted({(x['playerid'], x['Series']):(i, x) for (i, x) in enumerate(Datas)}.values())]
```